# Converting a two-part formula into a one-part formula in functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I was given 
$$s = \begin{cases}
\phantom{360-\;}10t & \text{if}\;\; \phantom{2}0\le t\le \phantom{3}9 \\
360-10t & \text{if}\;\; 27<t\le 36
\end{cases}$$

And was instructed to change the formula where it ends up like this:
$$s = 180-|180-10t| \quad \text{if} \ 0\le t\le 9 \ \text{or} \ 27 < t \le 36$$

I'm not quite sure how do you end up with the end result. I tried graphing it, but it didn't make quite a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Graphing, alas, is over emphasised.
If 0 <= t <= t, then 180 - 10t is positive
and s = 180 - (180 - 10t) = 10t.
If 27 <= t <= 36, then 180 - 10t is negative and s = ...